# Rails Polymorphic POST test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, minitest, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic model `Note`:

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :commentor, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
    belongs_to :program
    belongs_to :organization

    validates :commentor, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:notable_id, :notable_type], message: "can only create one note. Please edit your existing note" }
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 150, message: "only 150 characters" }
    validates :program, presence: true
    validates :organization, presence: true
end
```

For the controllers I have it set up as follows:
`app/controllers/tools/workouts/notes_controller.rb`

```
class Tools::Workouts::NotesController < Tools::NotesController
    before_action :set_routine


    private

    def set_routine
        @notable = current_program.workouts.find(params[:workout_id])
    end
end
```

Then:
`app/controllers/tools/notes_controller.rb`

```
def create
    @note = @notable.notes.new(note_params)
    @note.commentor = current_user
    @note.organization = current_organization
    @note.program = current_program
    respond_to do |format|
        if @notable.save
            flash[:success] = t(".success")
            format.html { recede_or_redirect_to [:tools, :program, 
            @notable, program_id: current_program] }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created }
            format.turbo_stream { flash.now[:success] = t(".success") }
        else
            flash[:warning] = t(".error")
            format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @notable.errors, status: 
             :unprocessable_entity }
            format.turbo_stream { flash.now[:warning] = t(".error") }
        end
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
    namespace :tools do
      resources :programs, only: %i[] do
        resources :notes
        resources :workouts do
          resources :notes, module: :workouts, except: %i[update destroy 
          edit index]
        end
      end
    end
```

I'm trying to test this action. This current set up works correctly when I play around with it in development. However writing a test for this seems to be a littler harder then it seems.

The test I'm having problem with:

```
test "should create note" do
    assert_difference("Note.count") do
        post polymorphic_url([:tools, current_program, @workout, notes]), params: { 
            note: {
                content: "Test workout note"
            }
        }
        puts request.POST.inspect
        puts polymorphic_url([:tools, current_program, @workout, notes])
    end
  
    assert_equal @workout.notes.last.content, "Test workout note"
    assert_equal @workout.notes.last.program, @program
    assert_equal @workout.notes.last.commentor, @user
    assert_equal @workout.notes.last.organization, @organization
    assert_equal @workout.notes.last.notable_type, "Workout"
end
```

The `paths` that are created are correct and the `params`, via the `puts`. But this test returns a fail with Note count not increasing, but statying the same.

How does one write test to test the create action for this?

Comment: first you need to determine if the problem is the test code or the app... what do you see in test.log? Is a note created, or not?

Comment: From development logs the note is created correctly. From the test the `params` are correct but the `assert differences` fails. I'm not sure what you mean by `test.log`, are you referring to the results of the test/ `puts` statement?

Comment: you should have a log directory under the rails root that contains a file called test.log. Do you see that? That's what I'm referring to.

Comment: Ah, ya I see it, I never know about this to be honest. But looking through the log I do see the test and the `note` is not being created. I see the `ROLLBACK` and `422`. I'll look through this more tomorrow and try to figure it out. This is still weird tho, I mean why would a `test` throw a `422` but `dev` throw `200`?

Comment: the first thing to suspect for a 422 is validation errors

Comment: Yup that is exactly what it is/was if you look at the `note` model I have a validation for `commentor uniqueness`, in which only one note can be created for a `commentor` on the `notable` object. For this test I'm using fixtures and a note was already assigned to the notable object and hence the error was thrown. Thanks for the help! If you create an answer I'd upmark it and all.

Comment: Also is there a way to have the validation messages appear in the test? I have one set if the commentor tries to add more then one note.

Comment: Validations are typically tested in model testing. In your case, it's a system-level test, and there's apparently no flash message notifying the user of the validation failure (by oversight? by design?), so there's nothing you can test at the system level. At the system level you can test for the presence of a flash message if you expect one.

Comment: Also consider using Ruby's `debug` function instead of `puts`

Comment: Are you referring to the `debug` from the debug section of the rails guide?